# override default validator in django

Tags: python, django, validation

Given the model field

`my_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[ MaxValueValidator(360) ])`

is there a way to override the min and max default validators? Above I'm simply adding a new validator and that works great on the server. However, I'm passing back a dictionary of validators to the client and two `MaxValueValidators` are set on the field instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into overriding the clean() function of your form?

As an example, heres something I have done in the past:

```
class ChemLabTimeSelect(forms.Form):

    from_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
                                       "pickTime": True}))
    to_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
                                       "pickTime": True}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        if cleaned_data.has_key('from_date') and cleaned_data.has_key('to_date'):
            total_days = (cleaned_data['to_date'] - cleaned_data['from_date']).days 
            negative_days = (cleaned_data['from_date'] - cleaned_data['to_date']).total_seconds() 
            if negative_days > 0:
                raise ValidationError({'from_date':["The from date is greater than the to date!",]})
            elif total_days > 7:
                raise ValidationError(["The amount of time selected is %s days which is too large!" % total_days,])          
        return cleaned_data
```

Also the model has a clean() override function and should be able to achieve your desired result. but one should be aware of the differences between the form's and model's clean override.

Comment: yeah but I'm not actually using the django forms, but rather using the validations to inform an angular client